# Extract rows considering a condition in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to extract the rows if all the columns are zero. In the first column of `df`, there is a list of gene IDs that are repeated per individuals in the second column. I want to extract gene IDs if the `df[,3:length(df)]` are all zero for all individuals in the next column.

```
> dim(df)
[1] 1040675      56

> df
ID     INDV     tra1   tr2   tr3  tra2   tr15   tr1b  
ENS777   1       1.2    0     0   1.6    3.3    0
ENS777   2       1.2    0     0   1.6    3.3    0
ENS777   3       1.2    0     0   1.6    3.3    0
ENS777   4       1.2    0     0   1.6    3.3    0
ENS999   1        0     0     0    0      0     0
ENS999   2        0     0     0    0      0     0
ENS999   3        0     0     0    0      0     0
ENS999   4        0     0     0    0      0     0
ENS888   1       1.2    0     0   1.6    3.3    0
ENS888   2       1.2    0     0   1.6    3.3    0
ENS888   3       1.2    0     0   1.6    3.3    0
ENS888   4       1.2    0     0   1.6    3.3    0
```

So, the out put would be `ENS999` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(all(unlist(dplyr::select(cur_data(), tra1:tr1b) == 0))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  distinct(ID)

#   ID    
#  <chr> 
#1 ENS999
```

Comment: Seems work but not correctly! I used 'grep' to chack if the captured IDs are belonging to the ones with all zero for all INDVs where it was not. The unique length of the column INDV is 300 which is supposed to be for the output too. While, the code gives IDs with zero in all the columns as output even if the condition is partially true, for instance for 150 INDVs.

Comment: are the columns `tra1` to `tr1b` in sequence i.e one after another as shown in this example? Are you using exactly the same code as in the answer? This works on the data that you have shared, so some information from your original dataset is not properly conveyed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, if all the columns are zero for all individuals.

You can try this:

```
library(data.table)

df <- fread("Book2.csv")
> df
        ID INDV tra1 tr2 tr3 tra2 tr15 tr1b colsum
 1: ENS777    1  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1
 2: ENS777    2  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1
 3: ENS777    3  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1
 4: ENS777    4  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1
 5: ENS999    1  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0    0    0.0
 6: ENS999    2  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0    0    0.0
 7: ENS999    3  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0    0    0.0
 8: ENS999    4  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0    0    0.0
 9: ENS888    1  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1
10: ENS888    2  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1
11: ENS888    3  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1
12: ENS888    4  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1

#take the column sums
df[, colsum := tra1+tr2+tr3+tra2+tr15+tr1b]

#take the row sums by ID
df[, rowsum := sum(colsum), by= ID]

> df
        ID INDV tra1 tr2 tr3 tra2 tr15 tr1b colsum rowsum
 1: ENS777    1  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1   24.4
 2: ENS777    2  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1   24.4
 3: ENS777    3  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1   24.4
 4: ENS777    4  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1   24.4
 5: ENS999    1  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0    0    0.0    0.0
 6: ENS999    2  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0    0    0.0    0.0
 7: ENS999    3  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0    0    0.0    0.0
 8: ENS999    4  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0    0    0.0    0.0
 9: ENS888    1  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1   24.4
10: ENS888    2  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1   24.4
11: ENS888    3  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1   24.4
12: ENS888    4  1.2   0   0  1.6  3.3    0    6.1   24.4

# Now you need the unique IDs for which the row sums are zero 
> unique(df[rowsum==0]$ID)
[1] "ENS999"
```